# Insert variable number of whitespaces in the middle of the string (to format "usage" help)

Tags: java

How to refactor this to be one line?

```
String format = "%-20s";
System.out.print(String.format(format, "Property name"));
System.out.println(": property value");
```

Likely I want to have something like this, the question is what `format` should I use?

```
System.out.println(String.format(format, "Property name", ": property value"));
```

Comment: Are you asking for a way to change the "20" above programatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
System.out.printf("%-" + length + "s: %s%n", 
      "Property name", "property value");
```

Comment: Why bother using `println` when there's `printf`?

Comment: @DaveNewton `printf` does not provide the new-line

Comment: It does when you put the %n in. That's what it's for.

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.printf(format + ": property value%n", "Property name");
```

But why bother?

Comment: I think (not really sure) that the point of the question is to be able to programatically change the amount of whitespace between the two fields. The question currently uses a value of 20.

Comment: @JohnB Okay. I think that the above could be extended easily enough.